# How to NOT select rows with a linking table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

Stores

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  ID        | STORE            |
--------------------------------------------------
|   -  1    | Store1 |
--------------------------------------------------
|    -  2    | Store2 |
--------------------------------------------------
|    - 3    | Store3 |
--------------------------------------------------
|   -  4   | Store4 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Users

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID       | USER           |
--------------------------------------------------
|   -  1    | User1 |
--------------------------------------------------
|    -  2    | User2 |
--------------------------------------------------
|    - 3    | User3 |
--------------------------------------------------
|   -  4   | User4 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

User_stores

```
--------------------------------------------------
| USER        | STORE            |
--------------------------------------------------
|    ---  1 --   | ----1----- |
--------------------------------------------------
|    ---  1 --   | ----2----- |
--------------------------------------------------
|    --- 2 --   | ----1----- |
--------------------------------------------------
|    ---  2 --   | ----2----- |
--------------------------------------------------
|    ---  3 --   | ----3----- |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using this for my select.

```
SELECT S.id, S.store
FROM stores S
JOIN user_stores L
ON S.id = L.store
JOIN users U 
ON U.id = L.user
WHERE L.user <> ?
```

My question:

I'm trying to select every store that is linked to everyone EXCEPT the current user (aka User ID). This query does select the stores that aren't linked to the current user, but there's still a problem.

My query still selects stores that the current user has, only if another user also has this store linked to it (because this is a row that's linked to the other user).

Is it possible to exclude these entries from the select statement with just the user id available?

**SOLVED**

```
SELECT S.id, S.store
FROM stores S
JOIN user_stores L
ON S.id = L.store
JOIN users U 
ON U.id = L.user
and L.user <> ?
and S.id not in (
select L.store from user_stores L
where L.user = ?
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN` to filter out the store that the given user has:

```
SELECT S.id, S.store
FROM stores S
JOIN user_stores L
ON S.id = L.winkel
JOIN users U 
ON U.id = L.user
and L.user <> ?
and s.store not in (
    select store from user_stores u
    where user = ?
);
```

Comment: I did not know that it was possible to put a select statement in a not in() and the like. You learn something new everyday! The query did not work for me unfortunately.  It produces the same result plus the store the user already has.

Comment: Updated. Can you try again?

Comment: It works now. I added some aliases at the ending select statement. Then it worked.

Comment: SELECT S.id, S.store
FROM stores S
JOIN user_stores L
ON S.id = L.store
JOIN users U 
ON U.id = L.user
and L.user <> ?
and S.id not in (
    select L.store from user_stores L
    where L.user = ?
);

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by using conditional aggregation over the stores in the `User_stores` table.  The two conditions appearing in the `HAVING` clause check that a store has all users appearing except for one, and that the user not associated is one which you choose (indicated by the question mark).

```
SELECT STORE
FROM User_stores
GROUP BY STORE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT USER) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users) - 1 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN USER = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```